# How can I add a Button to the end of this form field and retain the Bootstrap styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styling, glyphicons

I'm trying to add a search glyph to a button at the end of this centered search bar.

Below is the style I want:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1>Jumbotron with form</h1>
       <form>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

But I want to to have a button a - something like:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
```

instead of the 
`<span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>`
 
but when I do this the button moves onto the next line and throws off my styling.

Comment: Try this: `.input-group-addon { display:inline-block; }` If that doesn't work, inspect the Bootstrap CSS and copy the rules for `.glyphicon` into `.input-group-addon`

Comment: thanks, but i dont want the addon at all - i want to replace it with a button but retain the style

Answer (score 2):

Using Bootstraps form-inline class and form structure will resolve your issue.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h1>Jumbotron with form</h1>
            <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg pull-left">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats great Brian, its solved the main issue, but now the input bar is far smaller than it was before - i want to retain the width of the class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" but this wont work now

Comment: edited post to use large buttons, you just need to add form-group-lg to the div containers and the class btn-lg to the button.

Comment: just noticed the column width part of comment, add the class to the wrapping div for the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/EzINgYeHD3)

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>Jumbotron with form</h1>
            <form>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                        <span style="padding:5px 0px 5px 0px !important" class="input-group-addon"><button class="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>&nbsp;Search</button></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```